# .isGestureDetectionAvailable() always returns false

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, gesture-recognition

This question was unanswered for some times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777519/isgesturedetectionavailable-always-returning-false) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125945/android-o-fingerprint-gesture-callback-not-working), I'm trying to use that feature for my app and I've encountered this same problem and the solutions didn't work for me. there is a fact that the method returns true in the pixel device VM but it never returns true in my Samsung device (SM-A205F). I've tested the code on many other devices too but the same problem still exists (their producer was Samsung too). the devices support Finger Print Gesture Detection too (it is possible to open the notification bar using finger print sensor gestures). Is it possible that the solution is adding a Samsung specific library to my code? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal) too although it was somehow something else. I couldn't find the said library in the link's solution.

**Manifest file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--suppress DeprecatedClassUsageInspection -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.taha.fgesture">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Fgesture">
        <service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/myfingerprintgestureservice" />
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**myfingerprintgestureservice xml file:**

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestFingerprintGestures"
    android:canRequestFingerprintGestures="true"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    />
```

**MyAccessibilityService class:**

```java
    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {

        serviceInfo.eventTypes = AccessibilityServiceInfo.CAPABILITY_CAN_REQUEST_FINGERPRINT_GESTURES;
        serviceInfo.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        serviceInfo.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_FINGERPRINT_GESTURES;
        serviceInfo.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
        //serviceInfo.notificationTimeout=100;
        this.setServiceInfo(serviceInfo);
        //Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: connected");
        mGestureController = getFingerprintGestureController();
        if (mGestureController != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: " + mGestureController);
            isFingerprintGestureControllerConnected = true;
        }

        mIsGestureDetectionAvailable =
                mGestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable();
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: " + mGestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable());
        isGestureDetectionAvailable = mGestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable();


        mFingerprintGestureCallback =
                new FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetected(int gesture) {
                        detectedGesture = gesture;
                        switch (gesture) {
                            case FingerprintGestureController.FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN:
                                Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetected: " + gesture);
                                break;
                            case FingerprintGestureController.FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT:
                                Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetected: " + gesture);
                                break;
                            case FingerprintGestureController.FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT:
                                Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetected: " + gesture);
                                break;
                            case FingerprintGestureController.FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_UP:
                                Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetected: " + gesture);
                                break;
                            default:
                                Log.e(TAG,
                                        "Error: Unknown gesture type detected!");
                                break;

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
                        //mIsGestureDetectionAvailable = available;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged: " + available);
                    }
                };

        try {
            mGestureController.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(
                    mFingerprintGestureCallback, null);
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: Registered");
            isRegistered = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: " + e.toString());
        }
        sendMessage();
        if (mFingerprintGestureCallback != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected: registered");
            mGestureController.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(
                    mFingerprintGestureCallback, null);
        }
        if (mFingerprintGestureCallback != null
                || !mIsGestureDetectionAvailable) {
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you found the reason?

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy no not yet. there seems to be no answer for this.